# how to prevent access builtins from exec, eval through function call

Tags: python

i have following code

```
a = 100

def foo(x):
    print "x is {}, a is {}".format(x,a)
    print "locals:" + '*' * 10
    print locals()
    print "globals:" + '*' * 10
    print globals()
    print abs(1)

def main():

    source = 'foo(x)'
    l = {'foo':foo, 'x':1}
    exec(source,{'__builtins__': None}, l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when a i run this , i still get result as below, but i am expecting that in function *foo* , i can't access globals, locals, or abs like these builtin functions, any one can help explain this , thanks.

```
x is 1, a is 100
locals:**********
{'x': 1}
globals:**********
{'a': 100, 'main': <function main at 0x7f68c1d37c80>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'play/eval_test.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', 'foo': <function foo at 0x7f68c1d37c08>, '__doc__': None}
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `foo` identifier point to a function that was defined outside the protected bloc. As such, it uses the global dictionnary of the module in which it was defined and not the one that is passed to the restricted environment.

To actually prevent builtins access from a function, you must define the function inside the exec bloc:

```
source = """def foo(x):
    print "x is {}, a is {}".format(x,a)
    print "locals:" + '*' * 10
    print locals()
    print "globals:" + '*' * 10
    print globals()
    print abs(1)
foo(x)
"""
```

But then you fall in another problem: as you removed all builtins, neither `locals()` not `globals()` are defined and `exec(source,{'__builtins__': None}, {'x': 1})` will fail with *NameError: global name 'locals' is not defined*

So you must put under the `__builtins__` key, the builtin functions that you want to keep:

```
exec(source, {'a': 1, '__builtins__': {'locals': locals,
                       'globals': globals}}, {'x': 1})
```

You then get as expected:

```
x is 1, a is 1
locals:**********
{'x': 1}
globals:**********
{'a': 1, '__builtins__': {'globals': <built-in function globals>, 'locals': <built-in function locals>}}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 2, in <module>
    'globals': globals}}, {'x': 1})
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in foo
NameError: global name 'abs' is not defined
```

Comment: very helpful , actually I am implementing some features that will accept user input as code to execute, but I know that eval/exec is some dangerous thing , so I am trying to figure out this kind of tricky thing. do you have some more metrial regarding this problem or about python execution details,  appreciated , thanks.